# Ember JS set request header

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to set my auth token recieved from the response after user registration into Ember Data request header.

Here is my application.js code

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  namespace: 'merchant',
  host: 'http://192.168.1.173:3000',


  headers: function() {
    return {
      "token":localStorage.token,
    };

  }.property("localStorage.token","token")

});
```

I am trying to set the header after receiving success response from my register user API call.

```
var register=this.store.createRecord('registermerchant',data);
  register.save().then(function(response){
    console.log(response.success);
    if(response.get('success')){


      self.set('token',response.get('token'));
      self.transitionToRoute('merchanthome')

    }
```

and

```
  tokenChanged: function() {

    localStorage.token=this.get('token');

    console.log(localStorage.token);

  }.observes('token'),
```

I am able to see the updated localStorage.token value however this value for some reason does not get set to the reqest header token key.

The token is not getting updated to the header , it is only after doing a page refresh that the new updated token is being sent to the server.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong,any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is not an observable Ember object, so your `property("localStorage.token")` will only be evaluated once. Instead make it volatile to re-evaluate the property every time:

```
headers: function() {
    return {
      "token":localStorage.token,
    };

  }.property().volatile()
```

Comment: Yes ,I too figured it out.Thanks cannot upvote answer as I do not have 15 reps.
Just out of curiosity how can I build an Ember Observable object around localStorage object?

Comment: You can wrap localStorage in your own object and delegate calls with getters and setters. You would need to use `get` and `set` to access it. For a generic ember-enabled localStorage which can store arbitrary data you would need to use use `unknownProperty`/`setUnknownProperty`.